# Click on specific drop down item which are used multiple times using sikuli

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I am facing a problem using sikuli.

In the attached toolbar image, i have same drop down menu for three time for different purpose. Using sikuli i want to click on the second  dropdown menu.

I am using the below code, but the problem is while running the code, it only click on the first drop down.

My code is:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();

    // Create object of Pattern class and specify the images path

    Pattern image = new Pattern(AppConstant.IMAGE_DIR+"toolbar.png");
    Pattern image2 = new Pattern(AppConstant.IMAGE_DIR+"import-button.png");
    Pattern image3 = new Pattern(AppConstant.IMAGE_DIR+"dropdown.png");
    //screen.wait(image.exact(), 10000);
    screen.find(image);
    screen.find(image2);
    screen.find(image3);
```

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scenarios with multiple similar patterns, the best practice is to use the surrounding elements as a pivot. In your case, if you know that you have another unique element in the same area of the element you wish to click on, you can find that unique element first and then search for the element you actually need around the unique element.

For example, in your case, you have the blue down arrow just next to the drop down menu button you need. So you can do something like this:

```
ImagePath.setBundlePath("C:\\someDir\\sikulipatterns"); //This is to avoid supplying directory for each pattern
Screen screen = new Screen();

Pattern bigBlueArrowPattern = new Pattern("bigBlueArrow.png");
Pattern dropDownPattern = new Pattern("dropDownArrow.png");

Region bigBlueArrowPatternRegion = screen.find(bigBlueArrowPattern);
bigBlueArrowPatternRegion.grow(50).find(dropDownPattern).highlight(1);
```

Here, `50` is the margin to be added around the region, so basically extending the region around the blue arrow. I included `highlight(1)` just to emphasize that the correct element has been located indeed but you should remove it and do whatever you wish with the found element.

Comment: i will try this and let you know.

Comment: yes, it works and this is the best solution for selection multiple same type of item.

Comment: can you pls add some more detail about grow(50), i mean is this like look 50 pixel left from bigBlueArrowPattern item ?

Answer (score 0):

First of All you need the Accessibility id of that element. if that element has AI(Accessibility id). Then you can iterate through the elements and access the desired index.

To get the AI in windows you can use Inspect (a Ai tool by miscrosoft).In mac you can get the AI using Appium.

If you have access to your developer source code you can find the Api there too.

ELSE : you can use the below code . Hope this will help you.

```
      Iterator <Match> matches  = screen.findAll("dropdown.png"); // s is screen
      Pattern pButton = new Pattern("dropdown.png");


      while (matches.hasNext()) {

        Match m = matches.next(); 
        i++;
        if(i==3) {

            screen.click(m); // click on drop-down
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            break;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Please read the question again. OP is using Sikuli, not Appium. Accessibility ID is of no help here.

Comment: If he can add extra tool inside his project than it can be more helpful for him.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt findAll and getlastMatches method and then click on the one you want to.

`icons = findAll(image3)
 mm = list(getLastMatches())
 click(mm[2])`

Comment: can you please make it more clear? i don't understand what have said.

Comment: Basically you can use the findAll method to store all dropdowns in an array variable and then work on it accordingly

Comment: Iterator<Match> it = screen.findAll(AppConstant.IMAGE_DIR+"dropdown.png");

     int i=0;
     while(it.hasNext()){
 
         i++;
         if(i==2) {
          it.next().click();
         }
         System.out.println("********************* "+i+"***************");
     }

Comment: how i can click on the third dropdown?

Comment: Try using an iterator flag. As soon as you find your sorted dropdown image, click on it and break out of your loop

Comment: Try using my latest answer. Hopefully that works for you :)